# How to get rid of this message about a failed install

Tags: apt, software-installation, java, software-sources

I installed Ubuntu 11 after its end of life. I then tried to install java from the repositories. However, the installation failed. Since then, every time I install some other package apt-get tries to install java again, but it fails and spits out the log below. I installed Java 8 manually, so I do not need to install java from the repositories. I just need this error message gone.

```
Processing triggers for ufw ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u3-0~eugenesan~natty4) ...
Downloading...
--2015-03-01 21:42:44--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com... 129.19.157.14, 129.19.157.15
Connecting to download.oracle.com|129.19.157.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2015-03-01 21:42:44--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com... 23.9.86.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com|23.9.86.140|:443... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name `www.oracle.com' doesn't match requested host name `edelivery.oracle.com'.
To connect to edelivery.oracle.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up openssh-server (1:5.8p1-1ubuntu3) ...
Creating SSH2 RSA key; this may take some time ...
Creating SSH2 DSA key; this may take some time ...
Creating SSH2 ECDSA key; this may take some time ...
ssh start/running, process 2415
Setting up ssh-import-id (2.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Update:
purge did not help....

```
$ sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  oracle-java7-installer*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 317 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 139 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 145152 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing oracle-java7-installer ...
update-alternatives: error: unknown argument `cdrom'
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
Downloading...
--2015-03-01 22:23:38--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com... 129.19.157.14, 129.19.157.15
Connecting to download.oracle.com|129.19.157.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2015-03-01 22:23:38--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com... 23.9.86.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com|23.9.86.140|:443... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name `www.oracle.com' doesn't match requested host name `edelivery.oracle.com'.
To connect to edelivery.oracle.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the annoying package? `sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer`?

Comment: I did...did not work.

Comment: Consider installing a supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @LivWireBT and others. Please do not close questions because you do not know the answer with lame excuses like EOL or something else. Real people are waiting for real answers. The fact the this version of Ubuntu reached its EOL is irrelevant. Because for many reasons I can not upgrade. Again, if you know the answer post it, otherwise, leave the question alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -r oracle-java7-installer
sudo dpkg --purge oracle-java7-installer
```

If the preceding does not work, you may try the following more aggressive method. Be aware, however, that it uses the rm command, which will completely remove files immediately and permanently from an important directory. Be extremely cautious.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Hello @scarface_90 . I just tried both. None worked....

Comment: i changed it a few, test and send me back the resault